# Video embed inside CSS hover menu

Tags: css, menu

I need to add a video embed (eg youtube) inside a hover menu that's made with CSS only. The embed works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. However in IE (version doesn't seem to matter) there is a problem (surprise surprise)

If I go over the embed in IE the menu disappears and the video cannot be watched.

Is there a way to make this work with CSS only?

Here's a simple demo and a fiddle that has the problem. Just open menu 2 and go over the embed in IE and the submenu will disappear. http://jsfiddle.net/wtpsh/2/

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <div><a href="#">Menu 1</a></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></div>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <div><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></div>
            <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/X111ImmD4Gw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li div {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
    padding: 7px;
    display:inline-block;
}

ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```